# How can I make Ninject kernel return NSubstitute mock object?

Tags: ninject, nsubstitute

I have static method in static class which injects my dependencies:

```
 public static void InjectDependency(NinjectModule module);
```

I have static property to get instance of each object:

```
 public static IKernel AppKernel {get;set;}
```

If I'd like to create an instance, depending on my injeced `NinjectModule`-derived classes, I use following code:

```
 IInterface instance = MyStaticClass.AppKernel.Get<IInterface>();
```

But now I want to make my kernel return mock object, created with *NSubstitute*. How can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Ninject MockingKernel](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.MockingKernel), with this when you are testing you dont use the `new StandardKernel()`, you will use `new NSubstituteMockingKernel()`- *in your case*, but the `MockingKernel` has support to **RhinoMocks**, **FakeItEasy
** and **Moq**.

Comment: Can you provide a little example, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the StandardKernel and bind the substitute:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
// Set up kernel

var substitute = Substitute.For<ISubstitutedObject>();
kernel.Bind<ISubstitutedObject>().ToContstant(substitute);
```